# Numpy remove column in array if first value in column is larger than last

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What's an efficient way to remove columns from an `NumPy` array if the first value is greater than the last value in that column. Let's say I had `b`:

```
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> b = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> b[0,0] = 9

>>> b
array([[9, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

And since the `b[0,0] > b[-1,0]`, you would wish to remove the first column and effectively be left with:

```
array([[1, 2],
   [4, 5],
   [7, 8]])
```

What's an efficient way to do this? I've seen it done with rows, with notation like:

```
b[np.logical_not(np.logical_and(b[:,0] > 20, b[:,0] < 25))]
```

But not with columns. Also, if transposing could be avoided that would definitely be preferable as I would like to use this on a large data set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use logical indexing:

```
new_b = b[:, b[0,:]<=b[-1,:]]
```

Comment: It should actually be `b[:, b[0,:]<b[-1,:]]`, but awesome, thanks

Comment: Yes, you want to keep the columns, which fulfills the condition.